# How can I print bean property in HTML tag attribute

Tags: html, jsf

how I can insert the value of image in the tag div?

```
<f:verbatim>
    <div style="background: #000  #{item.image} no-repeat 0 0 
        backround-size:cover;height:90px;width:160px">          
    </div>
</f:verbatim>
```

n this way it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `#{item.image}`binary data or an url?

Answer (score 1):

The presence of `<f:verbatim>` indicates that you're using jurassic JSP instead of its successor Facelets. Both JSP and `<f:verbatim>` are deprecated since JSF 2.0 (in 2009 already). The `<f:verbatim>` has no utter value in Facelets.

EL in template text like as in your attempt is **not supported** in JSP. It's only supported in Facelets. In JSP, EL is only evaluated in attributes of a JSP tag. So, you need a real JSF component instead of a plain HTML `<div>` which is basically "template text".

To let JSF generate a `<div>` element, use `<h:panelGroup layout="block">`.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" style="background: #000 #{item.image} no-repeat 0 0 
    backround-size:cover;height:90px;width:160px">         
</h:panelGroup>
```

In case you're *actually* using JSF 2.x on Facelets, but got mixed up with JSF 1.x practices because you've only read prehistoric books/resources targeted on JSF 1.0/1.1, where `<f:verbatim>` is demonstrated in such way, then simply get rid of `<f:verbatim>` tag and throw away those ancient resources and remember to pay attention to JSF version mentioned in those resources. It must be at least JSF 2.0.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've a typo in your inline CSS.